# Command line to transpose/unfold nested data within rows

Tags: regex, awk, command-line-interface

What's a smart and succinct way to unfold a line with delimited data? I can imagine a little script that processes line by line in ruby or perl, but can this be done elegantly?

From this:

```
 alpha @ ä | b | ç @ 1.1 | 2.1 | 3.1
 beta @ d | é | f @ 4.2 | 5.2 | 6.2
```

Into this:

```
 alpha @ ä @ 1.1
 alpha @ b @ 2.1
 alpha @ ç @ 3.1
 beta @ d @ 4.2
 beta @ é @ 5.2
 beta @ f @ 6.2
```

There are always 3 main columns, always content in column 1, and an unpredictable amount of non-null content in columns 2 and 3. For example, I could have 50 items on a row. Columns 1 & 2 might have [^a-zA-Z] (i.e., unicode). As long as it's succinct, a one-liner in perl or ruby would be ok. sed is always welcome, but I think this is beyond sed's ability.

I am using MacOS.

*My actual data has a slightly different format and delimiters; e.g., I use tabs instead of @, and no spaces, but the @ is easier to read here. And it's trivial for me to conform my data to this or a similar syntax.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F@ '{n=split($2,a,"|"); split($3,b,"|"); for (i=1;i<=n;i++)print $1 "@" a[i] "@" b[i];}' file
alpha @ ä @ 1.1 
alpha @ b @ 2.1 
alpha @ ç @ 3.1
beta @ d @ 4.2 
beta @ é @ 5.2 
beta @ f @ 6.2
```

The above was tested using GNU awk.

#### How it works

- `-F@`

  Set the field separator to `@`.  If you prefer tabs, just replace `@` with `"\t"`.
- `{n=split($2,a,"|"); split($3,b,"|")`

  Split the second and third columns by separator `|` and store the results into, respectively, arrays `a` and `b`.  The length of array `a` is saved in variable `n`.
- `for (i=1;i<=n;i++)print $1 "@" a[i] "@" b[i]`

  Print the output.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'[@|]' -v OFS='@' '{n=(NF-1)/2; for (i=2;i<=(n+1);i++) print $1, $i, $(i+n)}' file
alpha @ ä @ 1.1
alpha @ b @ 2.1
alpha @ ç @ 3.1
beta @ d @ 4.2
beta @ é @ 5.2
beta @ f @ 6.2
```

Comment: That's the problem with accepting the first answer you get that produces the output you expect - it discourages anyone else from posting an alternative answer that might be better in some way. In this case in addition to brevity, the main benefit of my answer is that it'll be faster since it doesn't need the 2 split() functions called for every input line nor the 2 associated arrays and it uses the builtin Output Field Separator char (`,`) instead of relying on string concatenation (very slow in awk) with a literal `@`. There may be better answers you're never going to get a chance to see too.

Comment: You're right, I guess I should have waited. I wasn't sure the best StackOverflow approach in this case, since I thought they like to close questions.  I switched the "check" to yours since it's more elegant. The prior solution was more of a mini program compared to yours.  However, when I time both solutions for my test file, both come out in the 12.1-12.4 second range.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't mean to be mercurial here, but John's was clear, and I think it was reasonable to close. His explanation (How it works) was also welcome, and I don't think his two splits are bad. Switched back to John's because I think it's easier for other people to use his answer in the future. I understand your point about the OFS vs. split.

Comment: No worries, doesn't matter to me either way which solution you pick, my point was mainly that when you post a question it's a good idea to give it some time before selecting an answer so you and others finding the question in future get a few different answers to choose from since typically once an answer is selected you get few or no additional answers posted for that question.